# Azure Devops - Pulling subset of pull requests in to Master branch for release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pull-request

We have a dev and a master branch. When making a change I take a feature branch from Dev make those changes and push them and pull them back in to Dev for a release pipeline to kick off to update our Dev database.

Some times for a feature there may be multiple pull requests as its quite a big feature i.e. one pull request will incorporate the table and stored proc and then later a second pull request may contain views, or something along those lines. In an ideal world they would all be in one Pull request but this doesn't always happen.

Now as not all work on Dev goes to Master, when I pull my feature branch in to Master, it incorporates the changes I made but also the differences between dev and master that existed when first taking the feature from Dev.

Currently to resolve I take a feature from Master, cherry pick the changes from my original feature branch so I just have the changes I want and then pull them to Master to update the Master.....however is there a better way around this?

Many thanks in advance for your help!